# WiX Burn Bootstrapper Localization

Tags: wix, burn, wix3.8

I have a custom burn bootstrapper application with localization in german (BurnUI_de-DE.wxl) and english (BURNUI_en-US.wxl). At present burn automatically starts in english. I don't know how to change the UI language at run time. The UI parts are designed in MVVM pattern and have a language selection drop down. I have a variable to detect the systemlanguageID like this

```
   <Variable Name="INSTALL_LANG" bal:Overridable="yes" Type="string" Value=[SystemLanguageID]"/>
```

Everything is in place. Now, how do I use this variable and instruct the burn engine to change the language?
Furthermore, any best practices to localize the bootstrapper ?

Comment: This might be of interest
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250597/creating-localized-wix-3-6-bootstrappers
as to handling multiple cultures.

Answer (score 2):

Burn is very particular about how you include other languages.

As long as you have localized your UI strings (eg #(loc.MyText) ) you can follow the good example here: [Bootstrapper in English and German](http://max.zamorsky.name/node/78).  Max's sample solution at the bottom of the page demonstrates all of the pieces so you can carry on to do any other languages that you need.  Burn will then automatically use the right language file based on the computer's LCID.

If you have localized copies of your license/EULA, this posting explains the exact path requirements which are also rather picky.  [Localized License File](http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Localized-bundle-Picking-up-the-right-files-td7265208.html)

Comment: There is a project on Codeplex that shows how to do the localization: http://classicwixburntheme.codeplex.com/

Comment: Codeplex example seems to be cloned on [GitHub](https://github.com/frederiksen/Classic-WiX-Burn-Theme).