# How to set Wix OutputName programmatically

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wix, windows-installer

We have a Wix bundle project and now need to produce an OEM-branded version of our product. I'd like to use the same bundle project to produce both the base product and branded bundles rather than creating a second bundle project.

I'm familiar the Wix localization functionality (WXL files), and it looks like I could use it for this, but I'm stuck on the OutputName of the bundle EXE which is defined in the WIXPROJ; it needs to have a different name for the branded version. That is, the same bundle project should produce both BrandedBundle.exe and BaseProductBundle.exe.

Is there a way to use the localization functionality to set the OutputName programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon further review, I see that the "Cultures to build" field in the bundle's project properties page is disabled, so it appears that localization is not supported for bundles.

I did find some suggestions here: [Creating localized WIX 3.6 bootstrappers.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250597/creating-localized-wix-3-6-bootstrappers), but it does not appear that it is possible to do what I wanted to do (change the OutputName) the way I wanted to do it (using localization).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it with the localization functionality, but there is a nother way to do this.

You can pass in a build parameter to the msbuild...

```
msbuild WiXInstaller.wixproj /t:Rebuild /p:DesiredName="OEMName"
```

If your Output name (in the wixproj) is defined as the following:

```
Application-$(DesiredName)
```

Then your output will actually be:  Application-OEMName.msi

You can then have your build configured to run for a bunch of different OEM's if you need...

```
msbuild WiXInstaller.wixproj /t:Rebuild /p:DesiredName="OEMOne"
msbuild WiXInstaller.wixproj /t:Rebuild /p:DesiredName="OEMTwo"
msbuild WiXInstaller.wixproj /t:Rebuild /p:DesiredName="OEMThree"
```

It will run the build three times, and each will have its own output name:

```
Application-OEMOne.msi
Application-OEMTwo.msi
Application-OEMThree.msi
```

Best of luck.