# WiX v4 Bundle: How to create a localizable bootstrapper application with multiple languages?

Tags: wix4

I am working with a WiX Toolset v4-based Burn installer bundle, and I want to provide the installer in multiple languages, specifically German and English. I have a slightly modified version of the `HyperlinkTheme` and two separate localization files, each containing one language. I am using the `WixStandardBootstrapperApplication`.

When I include both localization files in my bundle project, I receive the following error due to the duplicate localization identifiers (for every identifier):

```
Error WIX0100: The localization identifier 'ProgressHeader' has been duplicated in multiple locations. Please resolve the conflict.
```

This issue prevents me from including both localization files in the Bootstrapper Application payload (as it was done with v3). I have already updated all packages to the latest version (4.0.0), but the problem persists.

How can I resolve this conflict and successfully include both localization files in my project? Is the localization process for Bootstrapper Application in WiX Toolset v4 different from v3? I cannot find any information regarding localization other than the LocalizationFile attribute of the Bootstrapper Application (https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/bal/wixinternaluibootstrapperapplication/#attributes) inside the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can include multiple .wxls as payloads but not in the .wixproj itself.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible that you give an example on how to properly localize a bootstapper application with WiX toolset v4 to clarify that not only for me, but also for mankind :)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250597/creating-localized-wix-3-6-bootstrappers/11402260#11402260 is still true in WiX v4.